# Visual c++ Assertion Error Moving Resources

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, resources, assertion

I am new to c++ and visual studio and what I am trying to do is edit a sample gui for a FLIR camera that was provided to me through an eBUS SDK. I am trying to move information and buttons relating to my camera into a dialog box that opens when I click the settings button. But as soon as I cut and paste the code to the dialog box I encounter problems. The gui builds fine, but when I run the .exe I get an assertion error.

This is the dialog box code

```
IDD_SETTINGS DIALOGEX 0, 0, 444, 319
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Settings"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,205,298,50,14
    //I want to put the buttons, labels etc here
END
```

This is the main GUI code where I want to move the comboboxes, pushbuttons, etc

```
IDD_PVSIMPLEUISAMPLE DIALOGEX 0, 0, 575, 284
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "PvSimpleUISample"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    PUSHBUTTON      "Select / Connect",IDC_CONNECT_BUTTON,10,16,86,16
    PUSHBUTTON      "Disconnect",IDC_DISCONNECT_BUTTON,97,16,87,16,WS_DISABLED
    LTEXT           "IP address",IDC_STATIC,10,41,45,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_IP_EDIT,65,37,119,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_DISABLED
    LTEXT           "MAC address",IDC_STATIC,10,58,50,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_MAC_EDIT,65,55,119,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_DISABLED
    LTEXT           "Manufacturer",IDC_STATIC,10,75,50,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_MANUFACTURER_EDIT,65,72,119,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_DISABLED
    LTEXT           "Model",IDC_STATIC,10,93,44,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_MODEL_EDIT,65,90,119,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_DISABLED
    LTEXT           "Name",IDC_STATIC,10,110,44,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_NAME_EDIT,65,107,119,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_DISABLED
    GROUPBOX        "Connection",IDC_STATIC,4,4,187,123
    LTEXT           "Mode",IDC_STATIC,10,144,55,8
    COMBOBOX        IDC_MODE,66,141,118,30,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_SORT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    LTEXT           "Channel",IDC_STATIC,9,160,56,8
    COMBOBOX        IDC_CHANNEL,66,157,118,30,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_SORT | WS_DISABLED | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    CONTROL         "Play",IDC_START,"Button",BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_TABSTOP,13,171,44,26
    CONTROL         "Stop",IDC_STOP,"Button",BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_TABSTOP,75,172,42,26
    CONTROL         "Settings",IDC_SETTINGS,"Button",BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_TABSTOP,135,172,43,26
    GROUPBOX        "Parameters and Controls",IDC_CONTROL_GROUP,4,206,187,73
    PUSHBUTTON      "Communication control",IDC_LINK_BUTTON,10,218,174,17,WS_DISABLED
    PUSHBUTTON      "Device control",IDC_DEVICE_BUTTON,10,237,174,17,WS_DISABLED
    PUSHBUTTON      "Image stream control",IDC_STREAMPARAMS_BUTTON,10,256,174,17,WS_DISABLED
    GROUPBOX        "Display",IDC_DISPLAY_GROUP,198,4,371,275
    PUSHBUTTON      "Display",IDC_DISPLAYPOS,205,17,355,254,NOT WS_VISIBLE | WS_DISABLED
    GROUPBOX        "Acquisition Control",IDC_CONTROL_GROUP2,4,128,187,77
END
```

I did notice in the **PVSimpleUISample.cpp** file this code which uses the resources that seem to cause the assertion errors

```
void PvSimpleUISampleDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_MODE, mModeCombo);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CHANNEL, mChannelCombo);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_START, mPlayButton);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_STOP, mStopButton);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_IP_EDIT, mIPEdit);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_MAC_EDIT, mMACEdit);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_MODEL_EDIT, mModelEdit);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_MANUFACTURER_EDIT, mManufacturerEdit);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_NAME_EDIT, mNameEdit);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_START, mPlayButton); 
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_STOP, mStopButton); 
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_SETTINGS, mSettingsButton); 
}
```

I just find it strange that the code builds correctly but then gives an assertion error when I try to open the GUI. Any help/advice that you can give would be greatly appreciated.

edit: The assertion error occurs in \mfc\dlgdata.cpp line 40. This is the block of code where it occurs

```
HWND CDataExchange::PrepareCtrl(int nIDC)
{
    ASSERT(nIDC != 0);
    ASSERT(nIDC != -1); // not allowed
    HWND hWndCtrl;
    COleControlSite* pSite = NULL;
    m_pDlgWnd->GetDlgItem(nIDC, &hWndCtrl);
    if (hWndCtrl == NULL)
    {
        // Could be a windowless OCX
        pSite = m_pDlgWnd->GetOleControlSite(nIDC);
        if (pSite == NULL)
        {
            TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Error: no data exchange control with ID 0x%04X.\n", nIDC);
            ASSERT(FALSE); //This is line 40
            AfxThrowNotSupportedException();
        }
    }
    m_idLastControl = nIDC;
    m_bEditLastControl = FALSE; // not an edit item by default

    return hWndCtrl;
}
```

Also after just moving one line at a time, I have found that the assertion error first occurs at

```
EDITTEXT        IDC_IP_EDIT,65,37,119,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_DISABLED
```

Comment: The assertion should have pointed you to the line that caused the assertion.  Also, put a breakpoint in that function and step one line at a time until the assertion occurs.

Comment: It points to \mfc\dlgdata.cpp line 40. If I had 2 more reputation I could post a picture showing the error.

Comment: hang on I'm finding the line now

Comment: That is runtime code.  Look in the call stack to see what function your program is calling that leads to that error.

Comment: Yes it looks like the problem is in the DoDataExchange method. That calls CDataExchange which is where the assertion error is at line 40.

Comment: Perhaps the Dialog box that I added needs its own class with its own DoDataExchange method?

Comment: `I just find it strange that the code builds correctly but then gives an assertion error when I try to open the GUI.`  A program building correctly has absolutely no bearing on whether it will run correctly.  All it means is that the program is syntactically correct, and the linker found all of the external functions you're calling.  No more than that.

Comment: Also, if you're new to Visual C++, the thing you shouldn't be doing is trying to edit something that you have no idea if the original code works.  Always start with a working example -- whether from a tutorial, "App Wizard" generated, etc.  More than likely, your control is not being initialized and you're trying to access it, or maybe a resource ID is conflicting, or some such error.  These errors are alleviated by taking a working example, or starting from scratch with app wizard and building the dialog from scratch.

Comment: The program that I am editing does work. It is a sample program that the SDK gives you to edit. What I am trying to do Is adjust/ add/ delete various aspects of the GUI so that it better suits our needs. It's probably a job for a proper programmer that is advanced in c++, but I have been tasked with the job so I have to learn as I go

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: So you're saying that without your changes, the program runs correctly?  In Visual Studio, does the resource view show the dialog?  If so, then you should *not* be cutting and pasting code in the .RC file.  You should be using the resource editor to add/remove controls.  It is very easy to mess up and duplicate a control's ID if you try to edit this by hand.  For example `IDC_IP_EDIT` has a number associated with it.  If it conflicts with another control's ID in the dialog, then things will not work correctly.

Comment: Yes, what I did was add a dialog box that opens when I click a settings button on the original window. The original window has labels, buttons etc that clog up the view and make it look complicated. What my boss wants me to do is simplify the design by only showing the bare minimum on the original window. So what I am trying to do is move the labels, buttons etc into the dialog box that I added so that they only appear when I click the settings button. I thought I could do this by just moving the code that has buttons, labels from the original window into the dialog box code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll play around with the resource editor and see if I can move the buttons that way